# How can I convert this into a Command for the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, command

I know how to bind the event but I can't workout hot to do the same thing from the VM:

```
void TapGestureRecognizer_ElderList_Single(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var stacklayout = sender as StackLayout;
    ListElders.SelectedItem = stacklayout.BindingContext;
    ListElders.Focus();
}
```

My understanding is that the View knows about the ViewModel, but the ViewModel does not know about the View. This would indicate to me that using a Tapped event in the Code Behind is actually the correct routine in this situation.

Yes? Ot can it be done from ViewModel?

---

## What am I trying to do?

If I tap of click to the left or right of the list view (outside the list itself) then it selects correctly and shows blue. This works as expected.

But if I click the item itself on the list, then by default nothing is selected. So we start with this:

```
void TapGestureRecognizer_ElderList_Single(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var stacklayout = sender as StackLayout;
    ListElders.SelectedItem = stacklayout.BindingContext;
    //ListElders.Focus();
}
```

Now when you tab or click the item itself it gets selected. But when I have two list views on my window I find that the selection is not always showing blue. It sometimes shows like a dark gray. I assumed this was because the list view did not have focus.

When I add that Focus call then it will show Blue consistently.

---

Complete XAMl so far:

```
  <ListView
        x:Name="ListElders"
        HasUnevenRows="True"
        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
        ItemsSource="{Binding EldersCollection}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElder, Mode=TwoWay}"
        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="2">
                        <Label
                            FontSize="Small"
                            Text="{Binding .}"
                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_ElderList_Single" />
                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.EditElderCommand, Source={Reference ListElders}}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, Source={Reference ListElders}}"
                                NumberOfTapsRequired="2" />
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: TapGestureRecognizers have a Command property expressly for this scenario

Comment: @Jason So where have I gone wrong? SelectedElder is mapped to the Selected item, and we do not have the ListView item in the ViewModel so we can't call Focus.

Comment: there is very little context here for me to understand what you're trying to accomplish or what specific problem you're facing.  If you're asking "how do I manipulate UI objects from the VM?" then it probably does make more sense to handle this as an event in the View, not the VM.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the ListView as CommandParameter to your Command in your viewmodel.

Something like:

```
<StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer
        Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{x:Reference ListElders}" />
</StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

<ListView x:Name = "ListElders">
  ....
</ListView>
```

in your viewmodel:

```
ICommand  TapCommand = new Command<ListView>(TapEvent);

 private void TapEvent(ListView lv)
   {
        //you could get the listview here
   }
```

**Update** (if you just want to hightlight the select item).

```
<ListView
    x:Name="ListElders"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
    ItemsSource="{Binding EldersCollection}"
    ItemSelected="ListElders_ItemSelected"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedElder, Mode=TwoWay}"
    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Padding="2">
                    <Label
                        FontSize="Small"
                        Text="{Binding .}"
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />                    
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

in page.cs :

```
private void ListElders_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //do something you want when you select item/
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can see how this will link to the code behind. My gut feeling here its that this is purely UI logic. I don't want to do anything it the model itself really. I just want the list view selected item to stay blue when clicked. See my updated question. In additiontion, I still don't know how to replicate the contents of the Tap handler in the Command version (it had the sender being the stack panel). I will I will just leave them as events in code behind.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I think this might be because you added `TapGestureRecognizer` to the StackLayout to conflict with the ListView `ItemSelected` event. Why don't you just use the ListView `ItemSelected` event instead?

Comment: I updated my question with my full XAML for the list view element for you to see if I ca do as you suggested. Sounds like you are right.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle If I understand you correctly you just want to highlight the item when you select it, right?If yes,you don't need to add the `TapGestureRecognizer`  like the  update above.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to "do" anything when they simply select an item. But it should do just that - "select" them. That was the fault. The thing I did want to do is invoke my Edit command if they double tap. That is fine. I will investigate what you have provided.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle So, you mean to highlight it when you double-click it, like when you click it ？

Comment: I am not going to worry about this now as what I have is working. This is expected behaviour. If you click once or twice that is going to set focus to that item. Except that twice will invoke my popup. I’ll leave this with my code behind. The real issue is that when you have two list views that the focus colouring does not work correctly on a Mac. Try it. Duplicate my listview so you have two. Remove the Focus call. When you start app and click first listview items they are blue. When you click other list, blue, go back to first, now grey.